# SQL DB provides CA in CAP?

Tags: sql, rdbms, cap-theorem

After reading couple of articles on google, I See SQL DB's are designed for CA(in CAP).

Here is my question:-

How can a SQL db like oracle provide CA without being partitioned tolerant ? Conside a case where we have two nodes one is master(for write)
and another slave is for read. There is network failure b/w master and slave then how come RDBMS db will provide both CA ?

Comment: "SQL DB's are designed for CA" is not clear, please explain. Why do you think an SQL DBMS can supply both C & A when partitioned? Why do you think CAP doesn't apply? CAP says if non-local access can fail then you have delay or inconsistency. "without being partition tolerant" *means* non-local accesses can fail. There's no conflict with CAP. Also just because there is no failure doesn't mean there is no choice between C & A. For concurrent users you either have to have delay or inconsistency--as reflected in SQL having transaction modes.

Answer (score 1):

SQL DB provides CA in CAP with the condition of  partition intolerant. It means they provides CA only when nodes are able to communicate without failure all the time Which to me looks impossible except single node DB which is not distributed